# Can I use PayPal to send payments on a client's behalf?

Tags: api, paypal

I'm developing a B2B web app and one of the planned features is to initiate and process payments from a user's PayPal account to a third party email (for example to pay a supplier on the user's behalf). Assuming I can get users to authorise our integration with their PayPal account, is there existing functionality from PayPal (presumably through an API) to enable us to do this? If there is does anyone know what the functionality is called and what level of authentication/permission I'd need from users?
Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PayPal Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13199099)

Comment: The link itself doesn't answer the question.  The answer is "PayPal Permissions API".  Since there is a source available for that, though, I went ahead and linked it.  If the link dies in the future, the answer is still the same.